# codeigniter : data not inserting in table using insert_batch

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried to insert data to table using insertbatch in codeigniter. I get the query, when I run that query into phpmyadmin sql query its works perfectly. when I call function its not working.

**array**

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [image] => 1_(1).jpg [package_id] => 45 ) 
[1] => Array ( [image] => 1.jpg [package_id] => 45 ) 
[2] => Array ( [image] => 2.jpg [package_id] => 45 ) )
```

**Codeigniter Controller**

```
$this->Settings_model->insertPackageImage($uploadData);
```

**Codeigniter Model**

```
$insert = $this->db->insert_batch('package_image',$data);
        return $insert?true:false;
```

**SQL query**

```
INSERT INTO `64_package_image` (`image`, `package_id`) 
VALUES ('1_(1).jpg',46), ('1.jpg',46), ('2.jpg',46)
```

when I run the sql code in phpmyadmin its works perfectly.

Comment: are you getting any error while inserting ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
if($this->db->insert_batch('package_image',$data)) {

    return true;
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct. What is different from the sql you are running on phpmyadmin and the one in your code is the table name. On the phpmyadmin the table name is `64_package_image` and in the code you called `package_image`

Try:

```
$insert = $this->db->insert_batch('64_package_image', $data);
```